# c# How to create several radio buttons in one grid cell?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, grid, radio-button

I have created a Grid in c# under silverlight like this:

```
Grid g = new Grid();
```

This grd "`g`" contains 3 row and  3 column.

and i want to display at cell(2,2)`(row, column)` using `c#` code only (**No xaml code**).
but i dont know statically the number of Radiobuttons to be created, The numbers of button to be created are know dynmically by calling a function FunctionCount(..);
I know i have to do something like:

```
int NumberOfButtonsToBeCreated = FunctionCount(..);
for (int i = 1; i <= NumberOfButtonsToBeCreated; i++) {
    RadioButton rb[i] = new RadioButton();
}
```

The first problem is rb[i] it don't work.And the second problem will be how to display all of them in same grid cell(2,2) one after other with a text like this :
[image]

**How to achieve could some one please help me to give a pece of code with explanation to make as reference for doing this? Thanks a lot.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StackPanel` to group your RadioButtons together:

```
Grid g = new Grid();

StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfButtonsToBeCreated; i++)
{
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
    rb.GroupName = "myButtons";
    rb.Content = "text to display";
    sp.Children.Add(rb);
}

Grid.SetRow(sp, 2);
Grid.SetColumn(sp, 2);
g.Children.Add(sp);
```

Don't forget to set the GroupName to make the buttons mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer let me try will come back if it works .But one question . How to manage grid cell size to accomodate the number of RadioButtondisplay ?

Comment: Hope it helps, for the cell size you should better post a second question, so other people can find it and it's not hidden in a comment.

Comment: Ok. let me implement this one first

Comment: sorry it created the radio button myButtons 3 times but it dont show  "myButtons" not even a single time Like i have Low,Normal,High and very high

Comment: And how is the code for selecting  the values on radio button? How we wil know that which button is selected bu user ?

Comment: The group name property does not set the label on the radiobutton, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I edited the answer, you can set the "Label" of each RadioButton via the Content property.

Comment: could you please  let me know that how is the code for selecting the values on radio button? How we will know that which button is selected bu user ? because your just create a Rbuttons. How it would be possible to determine which button is checked ?

Comment: could you please complete the answer so that would be able to tick mark it, it would be helpful for other user. The most important part to code is: How we will know that which button is selected bu user ? because your just create a Rbuttons. How it would be possible to determine which button is checked ?